# Writing values in certain positions in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

so I have this array:

```
ab = 3
cd = 4    
array = zeros(ab, cd);
```

which gives us an array looking like:

```
 0     0     0     0   
 0     0     0     0   
 0     0     0     0
```

now I'd like to fill each line with certain values. I have two classes with two properties I substract from each other.

so the first entry in the first line should be computed by:

```
xxx = class1{1}.property - class2{1}.property
```

the second entry in the first line should be filled by:

```
xxx = class1{1}.property - class2{2}.property
```

third entry:

```
xxx = class1{1}.property - class2{3}.property
```

the first entry in the second line should be computed by:

```
xxx = class1{2}.property - class2{1}.property
```

I tried:

```
for cc = 1:ab
  for hh = 1:cd
  array(cc, hh) = class1{cc}.property - class2{hh}.property
  end
end
```

However, matlab keeps telling me:"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."
I do understand what the problem means but I don't know how address it :/

edit:

the array should look like:

```
(class1{1}.property - class2{1}.property)         (class1{1}.property - class2{2}.property)
(class1{2}.property - class2{1}.property)         (class1{2}.property - class 2{2}.property)
```

Comment: without knowledge about `class1{...}.property` it will be hard to answer. How you generate these variables?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The values concerning the property of class1 are generated within class 1, whereas the values for the property of class 2 are generated within the main and passed onto the class. @schorsch: I mentioned the error, the desired behavior and I tried giving you a code example that symbolizes the desired function. However, thanks for the link.

Comment: Without knowing what `class1{1}.property` etc. contain, though, the code is not runnable, as was mentioned earlier - so we did not have "the shortest code necessary to reproduce (the error) in the question itself".

Answer (score 1):

As was said in comments, it's hard to know without more knowledge of the code, but it could be occurring because one or more of your class properties have more than one value. You could try something like the following to catch if the class properties are larger than 1 value.

```
for cc = 1:ab
  for hh = 1:cd
  temp = class1{cc}.property - class2{hh}.property;
  if length(temp) > 1
      keyboard
  end
  array(cc, hh) = temp;
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe the cause of the problem is that class1.property as well as class2.property are vectors? Now that I used norm(class1{1}.property - class2{1}.property), the code works just fine. However, thanks to you mentioning the length, I had this idea :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

The dimension mismatch error was due to me adding vectors (class1.property aswell as class2.property were vectors!)to each array entry.